# Changing the length of our from display name question

Tags: marketing-cloud, email

We are using Salesforce Marketing Cloud and we looking to change our from display name to be a little longer.

Example name:

Current from display name: Shoe Store Canada

New from display name to be updated to: Elite Shoe Store Canada

I know we are able to under our sender profile from display name easily, is there any implications/restrictions we need to be aware of before making the update?

Thank you

- Mike

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After anywhere from 15-30 characters, most email clients will abbreviate the from name in your inbox. ([ref](https://blog.aweber.com/email-marketing/from-line-length.htm)). So as long as the prepend addition is something that enables recognition from your recipients and/or that the appended info is not necessary to be viewed that should be fine. E.g. 'Elite Shoes - your store of choice' works as it has the important part first. But doing 'Your Store of Choice - Elite Shoes' could result in the recognizable part being truncated.

Also, you need to check the break points to make sure it does not cut off in a potentially inappropriate way.  For instance: "Mushrooms and Shitake" could potentially be cut short to be "Mushrooms and Shit" which would likely turn off a majority of your clients and/or potentially cause complaints. Or something like 'Bob Bank says FUNDING IS HERE' could be cut to 'Bob Bank says FU'.

Outside of those considerations, there is always the deliverability consideration - but from my understanding that is fairly low on the scale of spam determination (outside relation to sending/reply email address and unmatched DNS and authentication, etc.)